# 301 Redirects: SEO Credit After Modifications to Redirect

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

I recently moved `www.example1.com` to `www.example2.com`.

Initially, for a period of perhaps 1-2 weeks, this move was most likely a redirect from `www.example1.com/blah` to `www.example2.com` (go to the new domain but don't find the content).

I decided I needed better redirects because I wanted credit for some links I had, and I wanted to make sure users finding my links got pointed to the new page. Since my link structure was different in the new site, I wrote a redirect for every piece of content. It may not be ideal, but now when a page is requested on `example1.com` it redirects to the correct content on `example2.com`. This does *not* work with individual assets, for instance some images which forum users linked to on my site. I made a few manual links to try to keep those working. But any "not found" resource will just bounce to the home page.

My old domain had a domain authority between 20-30, but my new domain has a domain authority of 1.

My question is this: now that I've changed my 301 redirects, does that change get detected by the G? And should I expect to get some of the domain authority back that I used to have? If so, what kind of timeframe should I be thinking?

Comment: Don't forget to approve an answer if you like it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Google will detect these redirects over time for sure. But domain authority is a [Moz](http://moz.com/learn/seo/domain-authority) concept (and it will detect redirects too). They update DA every couple of weeks. Hence, you are going to have to wait for the next updates to see the impact. Remember that DA has no impact on Google rankings.

When you use 301 redirects, you loose a bit of link juice. Say your page on `siteA.com` has 70 units of link juice, the corresponding page on `siteB.com` will only have 65 units of link juice from the redirect (I am not saying these are exact numbers, it is just to give an idea of what happens). But don't worry too much about this, if your content was good on site A, it will still be good on site B, and on the long run, it will rank as well.

Answer (score 1):

The change **will** be detected by Google, don't worry about that. Moreover, like you applied 301 redirects in a correct way (each old pages to new ones), you would get your domain authority back.

You just need to wait a little bit in order to let Google discover these redirects. It's hard to say when because nobody knows when Google bots will find links to your old site on the web.

Comment: For more information, you lose a little bit SEO value by applying 301 redirects.

Comment: Thanks! So even if you've applied a 301 redirect before to a resource, that redirect is indexed but then if the 301 redirect for the same resource changes, eventually that changed redirect should get indexed too? That's great to know.

Comment: In other words, originally the redirects were bad but I corrected them.

Comment: Google bots crawl the web without taking a break. Thus, they will find and follow your redirect each time you change it. If your 301 redirects are now good, just wait and see your ranking come back to the SERPs.

Answer (score 1):

All of these answers are correct. However, there is something you are missing.

One overlooked aspect of redirecting from an old domain to a new domain is that the new domain must begin to stand on it's own at some point. As long as the 301 redirects remain, you will continue to benefit from the old domain. However, if the 301 redirects begin to fail, typically this is when the old domain is not renewed, then the benefit ceases.

The first thing anyone would need to do is to begin building links directly to the new domain. You will not have the benefit of metrics such as domain age and so on with a new domain if the old domain disappears, but that will return as the domain ages. It is important to build a stronger link profile for the new domain to out-perform the link profile that exists for the old domain. You will likely want to drop the old domain at some point. It is always a good idea to prepare for this even if dropping the old domain is not your intent.

Comment: That's a good idea, and it wouldn't be a bad idea to document the link profile and whatever other metrics I can get on the old domain to help guide that decision in the future

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am agree with Jverstry.
Google will definitely detect your website. And the problem of "Not Found". Please check your redirection method. If there is any problem then resolve it. And if not then i suggest you should again make redirection and check. If your previous site have good rank in search engine then don't worry your new site will rank well. But it takes some time. So wait and watch and keep updated your website.